# Annotations gone or missing in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In ADF pipeline there is supposed to be Annotations field but I cannot find it in any of my pipelines. Where else to add annotations?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are checking at the wrong place. It is in the properties. Top right corner

[image]